# C# Flee Framework and Outsystems

Tags: c#, .net, outsystems, flee

So I am using the .NET flee expression evaluator and consuming it in Outsystems. It's working great but I have some custom specifications that I don't know I can achieve using this.

Basically, I am building a custom exceptions builder for the clients, so they can use fields of a form as variables and then I replace the variables with real-time values and evaluate the expression to check if it's either True or False. If it's True then I will highlight the fields.

To give a specific example:

1. I have a form with, for example, 3 input fields, each input has a code, let's say *Code_1*, *Code_2*, *Code_3*
2. My formula string will be like this: `Code_1 = "sometest" Or Code_2 = "tbd" Or Code_3 = "123"`. Real-time values: `Code_1 = "outsystems", Code_2 = "tbd", Code_3 = ""`
3. After evaluating this with Flee if any of these fields get a true result, all 3 fields will be highlighted in red, but I would like to highlight only the ones that really return true, in that example only the *Code_2* field.

Any ideas if that is possible?

Thank you

I tried to split the formula into smaller branches but I still find some issues there.